# How to get the progress Url working when uploading?

Tags: progress-bar, dailymotion-api

I am wondering how to implement the progress bar/url function? I have only found limited info about it, and cant see how to get this working.Thanks.

Comment: can you detail what you mean? not sure what you want to do exactly. An example?

Comment: In the video uploading process, we use the GET method "https://api.dailymotion.com/file/upload?access_token=".$accesstoken; and get the response from the JSON file which includes progress_url.

We are unsure how to use this response to show the progress of the video upload. The documentation under File->File Upload Response, refers to showing the precent, elapsed time etc... but not how to actually show this.
Do we need to use JavaScript to show this? Or do you have any good examples of how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

For making a progress bar, you will need:

- information of progress, you can find this using dailymotion API. See paragraph below.
- displaying the progress. I have no recommendation but a simple google search will help. For example, the HTML5 `progress` element is a good start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Progress I've never tried it but you can also test something such as http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/

For information of progress, you can have:

- download video progress: requesting `https://api.dailymotion.com/file/upload` provides you with both a `upload_url` and a  `progress_url` that provides info on the progress of current upload (cf https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#file_upload-fields)
- encoding progress: there are two interesting fields on the video object: `encoding_progress` (https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video-encoding_progress-field) and `publishing_progress` (https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video-publishing_progress-field)